Internal Server Error: TypeError: response.status is not a function
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export const GET = async (req, response, next) => {
  try {
    console.log('Connected to Database via Prisma');
    const movies = await prisma.movies.findMany();
    console.log('Fetched movies:', movies);
    console.log(response);
    response.status(200).json(movies);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Internal Server Error:', error);
    if (!response.headersSent) {
      response.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
  } finally {
    await prisma.$disconnect().catch((disconnectError) => {
      console.error('Failed to disconnect:', disconnectError);
    });
  }
};


When i run this i get Internal Server Error: TypeError: response.status is not a function
but when i console.log the movies i get the right list i'm wondering why the response is giving me errors
i'm expecting a response to the .jsx component which looks like this
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const MoviesComponent = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMovies = async () => {
      try {
        console.log('Fetching movies...');
        const response = await fetch('/api/movies');
        if (!response.ok) {
            console.log(response)
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        setMovies(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch movies:", error);
        setError("Failed to fetch movies. Please try again later.");
      }
    };

    fetchMovies();
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return <p>{error}</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {movies.map(movie => (
          <li key={movie.id}>
            <strong>{movie.movie_name}</strong> ({movie.release_year})
            <p>Cast: {movie.cast.join(', ')}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MoviesComponent;




i would really appreciate help with this as i have tried fixing this for the past 12 hours with no fix just for a route.js file contacting a mongodb server to get some data

In the App router, the second parameter of route handler is the event not the response. The third parameter next doesn't exist in Next.js App Router. It's in some other frameworks like Express.js
To send a response you can use the built-in Response API or import the NextResponse class from "next/server";
//  app/api/route.js

export const GET = async (req, response, next) => {
  // ...
  return Response.json(movies, { status: 200 });
}

Or
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"

// ...

return NextResponse.json(movies, { status: 200 })

